# Logical indexing on large matrix takes too long

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have table that is 4 million x 15. I'm apply a mask like so:

```
curData = data(curCodeMask & curEstDateMask,:);
```

The mask generally pulls out around 5 records at a time. I'm looping through 686,000 unique identifiers in data and applying a series of functions.

I just ran the profiler that revealed that this line is taking up 71.6% of the time to run this function. That seemed very odd. Running through a 1000 indentifiers took 3 mins, meaning that I can't getting through 686,000 in a reasonable time.

Any suggestions to speed up the process or explanations of why this mask is a challenge to apply?

**EDIT**

```
test = repmat(cell2table(repmat({'AAA'},1,15)),4000000,1);
test([5500,60000,292404,290014,205802],1) = {'BBB'};
mask = strcmp(test.Var1,{'BBB'});
tic;test(mask,:);toc;
tic;test(find(mask),:);toc;
```

The first line takes 0.078991 seconds while the second line takes .004005 seconds. I'm changing my code to use find for now. Anyone have an explanation of why the logical index takes so much longer?

Comment: You're asking MATLAB to make a logical comparison of 8 million elements for every loop iteration, obviously that's going add up to a lot of time. Without any context of what operations you're doing and why you chose to do it this way it's not really possible to answer your question. At the very least I would suggest providing a [mcve], and I'd also say that this is probably more applicable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: just provided a good example. very confused at the result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that referencing matrices using `find` is faster because when a logical vector is passed to `subsref` (it is the function that Matlab calls when you reference part of an array using `A(b)` notation), it has to perform a check for every single value if it's zero or one. If one then fetch value, if zero then do nothing. The number of these checks performed is always the same: `4e6` in your example. On the other hand, when you use `find`, you pass a much smaller number of indices to `subsref`, `5` in your example, and the number of operation needed to complete the task is much-much smaller. This can be illustrated by the following code based on your example:

```
N = 4000000; 
test_ = repmat(cell2table(repmat({'AAA'},1,15)),N,1);

for i = 1000:50000:1000000
    test = test_;
    test(randi(N, i,1),1) = {'BBB'};
    mask = strcmp(test.Var1,{'BBB'});
    tic;test(mask,:);toc;
    tic;test(find(mask),:);toc;
    fprintf('\n');
end
```

Here, we gradually increase the number of `1`s in the mask and measure the time for logical indexing and explicit indexing, using `find`. If you run it, you will notice how the second operation increases considerably in time with each iteration while the first remains in the same order of magnitude (although does increase with the number of `1`s in the mask array):

```
Elapsed time is 0.139837 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.008691 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.157868 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.052939 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.202240 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.072856 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.251927 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.107802 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.273101 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.115091 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.304513 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.140899 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.320670 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.145321 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.363253 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.147760 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.351677 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.183472 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.365312 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.174972 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.410181 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.182656 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.410353 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.220691 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.424916 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.194585 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.451175 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.212605 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.471104 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.218952 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.495794 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.233784 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.513798 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.257506 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.523019 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.262233 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.540470 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.281143 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.543509 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.283295 seconds.
```

So, to conclude, use: `test(find(mask),:)` when you know that the number of members in `mask` that are equal to `1` or `sum(mask)`, is small compared with the total size of your array, `length(mask)`. How small, you ask? You will have to do a bit of experimenting on your machine for your specific case. However, from the toy example above it seems that for large enough arrays, `find` is better than straight up logical (at least for `table` class).